# error when compile android_x86 iso image

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I download the source code of android (kitkat-x86 branch) and then I compile it with Target product android_x86.

```
make -j2 iso_img TARGET_PRODUCT=android_x86
```

I follow all instruction indicated at this [link](http://www.android-x86.org/getsourcecode)

but I get this error message

```
    Copying: out/target/common/obj/APPS/ContactsProvider_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar
Copying: out/target/common/obj/APPS/SettingsProvider_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar
Copying: out/target/common/obj/APPS/SystemUI_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar
Copying: out/target/common/obj/APPS/TeleService_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar
target Symbolic: sqlite3 (out/target/product/x86/symbols/system/xbin/sqlite3)
target Symbolic: binderAddInts (out/target/product/x86/symbols/data/nativebenchmark/binderAddInts)
target Dex: telephony-common
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Copying: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/mms-common_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar
Copying: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/services_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar
Copying: out/target/common/obj/APPS/BasicSmsReceiver_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar
target Symbolic: libandroidfw (out/target/product/x86/symbols/system/lib/libandroidfw.so)
target Symbolic: libEGL (out/target/product/x86/symbols/system/lib/libEGL.so)
target Strip: libinput (out/target/product/x86/obj/lib/libinput.so)
target Strip: libstagefright_foundation (out/target/product/x86/obj/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so)
target Strip: libbcc (out/target/product/x86/obj/lib/libbcc.so)
Install: out/target/product/x86/system/lib/libinput.so
Install: out/target/product/x86/system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so
Copying: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v4-ics_intermediates/emma_out/lib/classes-jarjar.jar
Copying: out/target/common/obj/APPS/Development_intermediates/emma_out/lib/classes-jarjar.jar
target Strip: atrace (out/target/product/x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/atrace_intermediates/atrace)
target SharedLib: libart-compiler (out/target/product/x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libart-compiler_intermediates/LINKED/libart-compiler.so)

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.util.ExceptionWithContext
        at com.android.dex.util.ExceptionWithContext.withContext(ExceptionWithContext.java:45)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:371)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:139)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:94)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:682)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.ConcreteMethod.<init>(ConcreteMethod.java:87)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.ConcreteMethod.<init>(ConcreteMethod.java:75)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:273)
        ... 15 more
...while processing <init> (Lcom/android/internal/telephony/gsm/GSMPhone;)V
...while processing com/android/internal/telephony/gsm/GSMPhone$1.class

1 error; aborting
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/telephony-common_intermediates/classes-with-local.dex] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Comment: Your link is missing ;) Can you edit please ?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

```
1. make sure your javadocs version is pointing to 1.6, check java and javac versions too.
2. make clean and make again.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

upgrading my jdk worked for me.  After updating i updated the JAVA_HOME environment variable and then also updated the same thing in android studio by going to file--->other settings-->default project structure and updating the jdk location path.

[image]